# enhanced config parser for python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, configuration-files, configparser

i am using configparser in python 2.7.  it lacks some key features which i need, so i am wondering if there is an alternative.

here are some features which i am looking for:

1. case sensitivity for sections and options
2. ability to reference options from different sections.  example:

   ```
   [foo]
   a = 1

   [bar]
   b = <foo::a>
   ```

bar::b would be 1

3. ability to include other files inline.  example
   my_include.ini

   ```
   [foo]
   bar = 1
   ```

main.ini

```
    [hello]
    a = 1

    include my_include.ini
    [bye]
    b = <foo::bar>
```

bye::b would evaluate to 1

4. ability to include files with variables in path.  example:

my_include1.ini

```
    [hi]
    a = 5
```

main.ini

```
    [foo]
    bar = 1

    # this would load my_include1.ini
    include my_include<foo::bar>.ini
```

5. ability to access debug info.  example, it can print which line of which file defined a variable.

anything out there with some/all of the above features?

thanks!

Comment: Case-sensivity can be implemented with ConfigParser using [optionxform](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.optionxform).

Comment: @phd thanks!  any suggestions for the other items?

Comment: It is only my opinion but you are setting yourself up for a fall, going down this road. The user is going to need a degree in rocket science just to configure the application, with bags of room to get things spectacularly wrong.

Comment: ConfigParser [supports](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.ConfigParser.get) primitive interpolation, but that's all. You can try [configparser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/configparser) backported from Python 3.5; but it also is much less advanced than what you're looking for,

Comment: I wonder if GitPython's [GitConfigParser](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.4/reference.html#module-git.config) can you give you the power of `git config` format.